How does one animate an annotation on a SwiftUI Mapkit Map?
I'm attempting to animate an array of annotations on a SwiftUI MapKit Map and not getting the behavior I'm expecting.  I see lots of examples on how to animate the map camera, etc, and even a few on animating annotations when using Map UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI, but nothing with SwiftUI's MapKit implementation to move any map content. Here is some code:
  var body: some View {
    Map(initialPosition: MapCameraPosition.camera(mapCamera), bounds: mapCameraBounds, interactionModes: [.rotate, .zoom, .pan]) {
      ForEach(viewModel.annotations) { annotation in
        Annotation("", coordinate: annotation.position, anchor: .center) {
              Text(annotation.number)
                .padding(4)
                .background(annotation.background)
                .font(.caption)
                .bold()
                .foregroundStyle(annotation.foreground)
                .fontWidth(.condensed)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .mapOverlayLevel(level: .aboveRoads)
        }
      }
    }
    .animation(.linear(duration: 1.0), value: viewModel.annotations)
    .mapControls {
      MapScaleView()
      MapZoomStepper()
    }.controlSize(.regular)
      .mapStyle(.imagery)
      .mapStyle(.standard(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll))
      .navigationTitle(viewModel.selectedTrack.name)
  }

Then, in the viewmodel have the following annotations array:
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {

  struct DisplayedAnnotation : Identifiable, Equatable, Animatable {

    var animatableData: AnimatablePair<CLLocationDegrees, CLLocationDegrees> {
        get { AnimatablePair(position.latitude, position.longitude) }
      set {
        position.latitude = newValue.first
        position.longitude = newValue.second
      }
    }

    let id: String
    let number: String
    var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let foreground: Color
    let background: Color
  }

  @Published var annotations: [DisplayedAnnotation] = []
  private var cancellable: (Any Cancellable)?

  init(source: SourceSubject) {
    cancellable = source
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .sink { subjectData in 
         let placeAnnotations = Dictionary<String, DisplayedAnnotation>()
         for place in subjectData.places {
            placeAnnotations[place.number] = DisplayedAnnotation(id: place.number, 
                    number: place.number, 
                    position: place.position, 
                    foreground: .white, 
                    background: .red)
         }
         annotations = Array(placeAnnotations.values)
      }
  }
}

Running the code I'm updating the annotation's position once every second, with the intent the duration will finish about the same time as the position gets updated.  But of course the annotation just jumps to the new location every second.
Any advice on how to fill the gaps of time with animation?  Is dropping down to UIViewRepresentable and UIKit MapView the only solution here?

show a minimal reproducible code, especially where/how you update the annotation's position once every second.

Added the combine processing to demonstrate the updating of the locations.
